# Begin with the unit ball $\mathbb{B}^n$ and identify antipodal points of its boundary sphere.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I want to look at the picture of this. This is a question from M.A. Armstrong and we need to show that it is homeomorphic to the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^n$ in $\mathbb{Е}^{n + 1}$ and partition it into subsets which contain exactly two points, the points being antipodal (at opposite ends of a diameter).

I have the intuition that the geometry is :

> I will have to essentially identify the points $\{x,-x\}$ such that $||x|| = 1$ and if $||x|| \ne 1$ . I was thinking of the fact that the equator will be something of a mobius strip (which is obtained by attaching $\{x,-x\} $ ) and the union of two discs.

Can someone explain me(with a diagram if possible ) where I am going wrong?